# C Programming terminology

Tags: c, variables, declaration

Take this declaration:

```
int i = 80;
```

This is my understanding of the terms used to describe each part (correct me if I'm wrong):

- `int` is the variable type
- `i` is the declarator
- `=` is the assignment operand

What term is used to describe the `80`?

Another example:

```
char *c = "a";
// char - variable type
// c    - declarator
// =    - assignment operand
// "a"  - ?
```

Comment: initial value..

Comment: The `=` marks the start of the initializer, and is similar to assignment but not identical (because, amongst other things, you can initialize an array but you cannot assign an array); the `80` is the initializer.  In the standard, you get _declaration:
declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt `;`_ and _init-declarator-list:
init-declarator | 
init-declarator-list `,` init-declarator_ and _init-declarator:
declarator |
declarator `=` initializer_.  Your `80` is just a particularly simple 'initializer'.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Also your full line is not a _statement_ but a _declaration_.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks. Edited.

Comment: "Take this declaration:" - Thats also a definition. Always use the most precise term. And there is no _assignment_.

Comment: The standard is very clear about nomenclature. What **specifically** did you not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the proper names of each part of the C syntax, you should go to the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and read the language grammar. The relevant (incomplete) pieces are:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list opt ;
    static_assert-declaration

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers opt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers opt

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

So for example:

- `static int x = 80, y = 90;` is a *declaration*.
- `static` is a storage-class specifier that is part of the declaration specifier.
- `int` is a type specifier that is part of the declaration specifier.
- `x` and `y` are identifiers (grammar is elsewhere) that work as declarators.
- `=` is a token that separates the declarator from the initializer. In this context it is *not* an operator.
- `80` and `90` are expressions that work as initializers.
- `,` is a token (not an operator) that separates one declarator plus initialization (*init-declarator*) from the next one.
- `;` is a token that marks the end of the declaration.

Comment: To expand a bit, usually people use the word operator for things that you use to build up an *expression*. For example, arithmetic operators like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, relational operators like `<`, `==` and `>=`, and so on. In variable declaration the  `=` is not part of an expression so it is not called an operator.